# fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86' Visual studio 2010 and cmake

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

I have a project which i have generated with cmake and running in visual studio 2010.I changed the configuration to x64,in visual studio my active solution and the Target Machine in(Properties->Linker->Advanced) is set as x64.I still get the linker LNK1112 error.Is this something which i set in cmakelist.txt if so what is the command?
-swetha

Comment: When you configured CMake for your project, did you select the "Win64" option?

Answer (score 6):

It's not something you'd want to set in `CMakeLists.txt`. Basically, CMake has multiple generators for different compilers. (The x86 and x64 compilers are two distinct compilers on Windows.) When you generate the build files, you need to pass along the correct compiler for CMake to use, or if you use the GUI, select Win64. From the command line:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 Win64" path/to/your/CMakeLists.txt
```

or whatever version of Visual Studio you want. You can see the available generators with:

```
cmake --help
```

If this didn't solve your problem, try it again after deleting the generated build files.

If that still doesn't solve the issue, you are linking to a third party dependency built for x86.

Comment: +1 This was my issue. We had `set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM x64)` in the CMakeLists. Removing that, and doing `-G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"` instead fixed the LINK1112 error. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete all *.obj files in your solution and let compiler compile all files again. This problem may cause of compiler try to reference obj files that was compiled x64

Comment: This is the real problem.   CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM is the correct flag to pass... since it works for all operating systems... not just windows.